# Ceiling function between topological spaces

Tags: general-topology

Somebody help me please!
Show that  the ceiling  function     $f\colon (\mathbb R,T)\to(\mathbb Z,T')$ given by $f(x)=\lceil x\rceil$ is not continuous, where $T$ is the  standard topology on $\mathbb R$  and  $T'$  is the order topology on $\mathbb Z$.
May you help me with a counter example (for this problem) where the  set  $O$ is open  in   $\mathbb Z$  but   $f^{-1}(O)$ is not open in  $\mathbb R$. Here is where I stuck, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: Each singleton $\{n\}$ is open in $\Bbb Z$; what is $f^{-1}[\{n\}]$? (You can replace $n$ be a specific integer, say $0$, if that makes it easier.)